# How to make an invite logger in discord.py?

Tags: python, logging, discord, discord.py, invite

So basically I am not requesting a code or something , I just want to know how invite loggers are made , basically by an invite logger I mean that I want to get the invite link , who was invited , invited by who , time of invite (I can do this one). So I want to know which attribute / command should I use to get the above details except time of invite. Your help will be really appreciated.

I did some searching in docs and found that `on_invite_create(invite)` , but according to docs it is called when an invite is created and not **when it is used** , hope someone can help me with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `on_member_join()` event does indeed not have a referrer, but you can manually find out by checking the invite list of the guild whenever a member joins.

A guild object has a coroutine called [guild.invites()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_member_join#discord.Guild.invites) which returns a list of [Invite objects](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_member_join#discord.Invite). These contain all information about an invite, by iterating over that list you can find out which invite changed when the member joined, thus you know:

- link with invite.url (or invite.code for just the letter code)
- inviter with invite.inviter
- Number of users they have invited (with that link) with invite.uses